# Setting checkbox fields via trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, fields, checkbox

I'm in the process of learning Apex triggers, and I've been attempting to write code that runs before updating a field.

The code should change the *Primary Contact* field to **FALSE** if the checkbox field *No Longer with Company* is **TRUE** and 'Primary Contact' is also **TRUE**.

However I keep running into some errors on line 3.  Could someone help me understand what is missing?

Here's the code I have:

```
trigger UpdatePrimaryContact on Contact(before update) {
    for (Contact record : Trigger.new) {
        if (record.No_Longer_with_company__c && record.Primary_Contact__c {
            record.Primary_Contact__c = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a close bracket in your `if` statement.

Change line 3 to:

```
if (record.No_Longer_with_company__c && record.Primary_Contact__c) {
```